# Using VARCHAR(Max) (That is really a string []) in an Inner Join using IN

Tags: c#, sql, arrays

What I am trying to do is connect two tables.

Table 1 will have this setup

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
   PkId INT Identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
   ListOfProducts VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
   ProductWareHouse VARCHAR(Max) NULL,
   CONSTRAINT PkId PRIMARY KEY (PkId)
)
```

Table 2 is set up like so

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table2
(
   PkId INT Identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
   Product VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
   ProductCost DECIMAL(38,2) NOT NULL, 
   CONSTRAINT PkId PRIMARY KEY (PkId)
)
```

Table 1's `ListOfProducts` is really a `string[]` and Table 2's `Product` links to Table 1's `ListOfProducts`.

What I really want to accomplish is an inner join of the two tables that would look in the `ListOfProducts` to actually accomplish the inner join so something like this

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
INNER JOIN TABLE 2 ON Product IN(ListOfProducts)
WHERE ProductWareHouse = 'Warehouse1'
```

`ListOfProducts` values would look something like this: `[Oranges, Apples]`.

Comment: Reconsider your design. `Table1` violates first normal form. It's almost never a good idea to store a list in a column. I say "almost" because somebody _might_ be able to come up with a valid use case, but I can't. If you have the option of fixing the data model, now is the time to do that.

Comment: If you have control over the structure of the tables, you should change Table1 so that ListOfProducts is not a string of different products.  It would be better to have one product per row.

Comment: I was just using this as an example due to the complexity of the actual tables, but after hearing about trying to save lists into a table I agree with you both. I will have to figure out a better way to set up some new columns in the tables I am trying to join Thank you both for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Method 1:

```
JOIN ... ON ListOfProducts like '%' + Product + '%'
```

Method 2:
Get rid of the left and right bracket first, then:

```
JOIN ... ON Product in (select value from string_split(ListOfProducts,', '))
```

Both are terribly inefficient.

Comment: This works, but you are right that it is terribly inefficient and I will manipulate the tables accordingly Thanks for your input!